# where clause in laravel for search

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to select rows from table **students** using laravel query for searching but on searching it's returning all rows from table.

```
$data = DB::table('students')
    ->select(['name', 'username'])->where('institute', $inst)
    ->where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('contact', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Try to use `toSql() ` to debug your SQL. Syntax would be `DB::table('students')->.....->toSql()`

Comment: what is the value of `$search`? if it is empty then all those fields will be 'like' that search pattern (`'%%'`)  ... and you will probably want to be grouping these 'where's in a particular way

Answer (score 0):

This is the thing, at least for what I can see, you have two kind of filters:

- Students that are in a given institute
- Students that have a similar username, name, email or contact than the given search term

If so, the problem in your query are the `orWhere()` clauses. Let's simplify your query to illustrate the issue:

```
$data = DB::table('students')
    ->where('institute', $inst)
    ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->get();
```

In the above code, the statement will get all the students that have the `institute` equals to `$inst` **OR** have a name similar to `%search%`. So, the results could include students that are not in the given institute. You see the issue now?

In order to first filter by institute **AND** get records that have a similar similar username, name, email or contact, you could wrap the second conditions in a closure. Try this:

```
$data = DB::table('students')
    ->select(['name', 'username'])
    ->where('institute', $inst)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {  // <<<
        $query->where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('contact', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: On searching it's returning error : Undefined variable: search

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to pass the `$search` closure. I've updated the code.